# Translation of "never take for granted"

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

"I wanted to let you know that I really appreciate your help and I never take it for granted."

> Je voulais vous dire que j'apprécie beaucoup votre aide et ____.

What should be the translation for "never take it for granted"? The translation [*ne faire aucun cas de*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/to-take-sb-for-granted) for "take for granted" seems awkward to apply in the negative with "never", as is the case here.

Comment: _et que je ne la prends jamais pour acquise_

Comment: The translation that you cite seems to be for taking **somebody** for granted (that's what "sb" means, I think, but I wonder why otherwise legitimate sites take this unnecessary short cut).  Since the "it" in your English sentence stands for a thing (i.e., the person's **help**), perhaps you could look for a translation involving  "something" instead of "somebody."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say:

> Je voulais vous dire que j'apprécie beaucoup votre aide et que je ne la prends jamais pour acquise.

Or:

> Je voulais vous dire que j'apprécie beaucoup votre aide et que je ne la tiens pas pour acquise.

(suggested by Papa Poule)

Also possible:

> Je voulais vous dire que j'apprécie beaucoup votre aide et/mais que je ne la considère pas/en aucun cas comme un dû.

(thanks qoba)

People will complain it is a *calque sur l'Anglais "take for granted"*, and it probably is, but I think it is commonly understandable in France by now, and [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendre+pour+acquis%2Ctenir+pour+acquis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprendre%20pour%20acquis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctenir%20pour%20acquis%3B%2Cc0) seems to concur (and this is only querying Google ngrams on the infinitive) (thanks to Papa Poule and sapienz for the updates on the ngrams graph).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I added that to my answer and attributed to you. I also replace my graph with yours :-)

Comment: "Considérer comme un dû"

Comment: You can also add [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendre+pour+acquis%2Ctenir+pour+acquis%2Cprendre+pour+argent+comptant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprendre%20pour%20acquis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctenir%20pour%20acquis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprendre%20pour%20argent%20comptant%3B%2Cc0) "Je voulais vous dire que j'apprécie beaucoup votre aide mais je ne prends pas cela pour argent comptant (idiomatic).

Comment: Oui! Une expression de plus, merci!

Comment: Thanks qoba! Voyons voir dans ngrams... Pas très populaire, mais je vais l'ajouter à ma réponse quand même.

Comment: Beware the the fact a random expression is more frequent than other ones on ngrams doesn't mean it is equivalent. *Ne pas prendre pour argent comptant* doesn't means at all the same thing as the other suggestions and would puzzle the receiver (I take your help with a pinch of salt / I don't take your help at face value ?!).

Comment: Not to mention *que je ne saurais en aucun cas la prendre pas pour argent comptant* is broken.

Comment: Ce n'est pas du tout équivalent. « Ne pas prendre pour argent comptant » n'a rien à faire dans cette formule de politesse.

Comment: @jlliagre - Hmmm - effectivement, vous avez raison, c'est bien différent, mais quelque part, ça pourrait passer dans ce contexte, bien que ce ne soit pas le sens - je vais l'enlever pour éviter une controverse.

Comment: C'est même tout le contraire, ça voudrait dire, je me méfie de l'aide que vous m'avez apportée, il y a probablement quelque chose de caché la dessous. Tout à fait insultant en fait.

Comment: Peut-être ... mais c'est un peu nébuleux pour moi, et le sens des expressions peut évoluer avec le temps :-) Cela me paraissait acceptable de premier abord, sans bien écouter ni faire attention. L'expression pourrait se prêter assez bien à un changement de sens qui conviendrait ici, si l'on y réfléchit. Mais peu importe, j'enlève de ma réponse.

Answer (score 1):

The closer equivalent would be *tenir pour acquise* or *considérer comme acquise* but I wouldn't stick to the English idiom and use the more idiomatic :

> Je tenais à vous remercier et vous dire que j'apprécie à sa juste valeur tout ce que vous avez fait pour moi.

Comment: by now, _tenir pour acquis_ n'est plus un anglicisme à mon avis. Votre proposition est excellente, mais dévie un peu du sens originel en anglais, qui est mieux maintenu par l'"anglicisme" maintenant accepté _tenir pour acquis_.

Comment: Oui, le sens de votre proposition est différent de l'anglais. Dans le texte de l'OP, on veut à mon avis signifier que l'aide qui a été fournie n'est pas considérée comme un _dû_, que c'est une _faveur_.

Comment: Je n'ai pas écrit que tenir pour acquis était un anglicisme mais que *take for granted* était une expression idiomatique anglaise dans le contexte particulier utilisé ici. Les expression idiomatiques ont un sens différent ou plus large que celui de l'expression sous-jacente et ne doivent pas forcément être traduites mot à mot dans d'autres langues. https://www.quora.com/What-does-taken-for-granted-mean

Comment: Vous donnez à "I never take it for granted" une connotation positive, alors que ce n'est absolument pas le cas!

Comment: @sapienz ?????? Qu'elle connotation négative faut-il alors comprendre ?

Comment: Dans le cas présent _tenir pour acquis_ convient bien pour rendre _take for granted_.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec jlliagre. L'expression en anglais est idiomatique, et il est difficile d'en produire un équivalent en français. Selon moi, il est mieux d'utiliser une alternative comme celle proposée par jlliagre.